# Why does this Switch/Case Statement always perform the default? AS3

Tags: actionscript-3

This switch/case statement always does the default, I don't want that to happen.  Also, I am getting no errors.  Can someone enlighten me as to what my problem is?  The function always traces what I expect it will, but I want it to place a bulldozer on the stage.

```
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.ui.Mouse;

//START SCREEN
var startScreen: MovieClip;
var bulldozer: MovieClip;


startClick.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, startGame);

function startGame(event: MouseEvent): void {
    startScreen.parent.removeChild(startScreen);
startClick.parent.removeChild(startClick);
var enemyGenerator: Number = Math.random();
switch (enemyGenerator) {
    case 0.8 <= enemyGenerator && enemyGenerator <= 1:
        stage.addChild(bulldozer);
        bulldozer.x = stage.x = 150;
        bulldozer.y = stage.y = 150;
        break;
    case 0.6 <= enemyGenerator && enemyGenerator < 0.8:
        stage.addChild(bulldozer);
        bulldozer.x = stage.x = 250;
        bulldozer.y = stage.y = 250;
        break;
    case 0.4 <= enemyGenerator && enemyGenerator < 0.6:
        stage.addChild(bulldozer);
        bulldozer.x = stage.x = 350;
        bulldozer.y = stage.y = 350;
        break;
    case 0.2 <= enemyGenerator && enemyGenerator < 0.4:
        stage.addChild(bulldozer);
        bulldozer.x = stage.x = 400;
        bulldozer.y = stage.y = 400;
        break;
    case 0 <= enemyGenerator && enemyGenerator < 0.2:
        stage.addChild(bulldozer)
        bulldozer.x = stage.x = 450;
        bulldozer.y = stage.y = 450;
        break;
    default:
        trace (enemyGenerator);
}
startClick.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, startGame);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are using it wrong.

**Question 1**: what is the value type of your `enemyGenerator` variable? 
  - Answer: int

**Question 2:** what is the value type of your switch conditions ?
  - Answer: boolean

So comparing an int with a boolean is always false...

```
 ex: 0.9 == true  // will be false
```

What you need is to change your switch into an IF --  ELSE IF condition... like below

```
var enemyGenerator: Number = Math.random();

if(enemyGenerator >= 0.8) 
{
    stage.addChild(bulldozer);
    bulldozer.x = stage.x = 150;
    bulldozer.y = stage.y = 150;
}
else if(enemyGenerator >= 0.6)
{
    stage.addChild(bulldozer);
    bulldozer.x = stage.x = 250;
    bulldozer.y = stage.y = 250;
} 
else if(enemyGenerator >= 0.4)
{
    stage.addChild(bulldozer);
    bulldozer.x = stage.x = 350;
    bulldozer.y = stage.y = 350;
}    
else if(enemyGenerator >= 0.2)
{
    stage.addChild(bulldozer);
    bulldozer.x = stage.x = 400;
    bulldozer.y = stage.y = 400;
}
else
{
    stage.addChild(bulldozer)
    bulldozer.x = stage.x = 450;
    bulldozer.y = stage.y = 450;
}
```

Also why not add the child buldozer before or after the IF statement.. except writing it always in each if / case branch?

Answer (score 0):

Case statements only work when you are equaling something exactly. Like this:

```
case condition 1:
```

If you want to do comparisons, you need to convert that to `if` and `else if`

Answer (score 0):

Your case statement is plain invalid. Switch-case operator only performs equality checks. If you perform a `Math.random()` call, you receive a value that's never strictly equal to a certain value. To make a selection out of a given `N` possibilities, you use an `int` and call random like this:

```
var r:int=Math.floor(N*Math.random());
```

Then, `r` will hold a value from 0 to N-1, which you can then switch for.

```
switch(r) {
    case 0: // bla bla
    case 1: // bla bla bla
    ...
    case N-1: // you know the drill
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a tricky one. Once things that people above answered correct is Action script has it's tricks.

Your switch CAN work if you just replace `switch (enemyGenerator)` by `switch (true)` .

I just wanted to show that what you want to do is possible, yet I'd advice the use of an if statement as described by Adrian.

Cheers